# While Loop Not Performing Main Function

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python script that uses a particular external application belonging to the company I work for. I can generally figure things out for myself when it comes to programming and scripting, but this time I am truely lost!

I can't seem to figure out why the while loop wont function as it is meant to. It doesn't give any errors which doesn't help me. It just seems to skip past the important part of the code in the centre of the loop and then goes on to increment the "count" like it should afterwards!

```
f = open('C:/tmp/tmp1.txt', 'w')    #Create a tempory textfile
f.write("TEXTFILE\nTEXTFILE\nTEXTFILE\nTEXTFILE\nTEXTFILE\nTEXTFILE\n") #Put some simple text in there
f.close()   #Close the file

count = 0   #Insert the line number from the text file you want to begin with (first line starts with 0)
num_lines = sum(1 for line1 in open('C:/tmp/tmp1.txt')) #Get the number of lines from the textfile

f = open('C:/tmp/tmp2.txt', 'w')    #Create a new textfile
f.close()   #Close it

while (count < num_lines):  #Keep the loop within the starting line and total number of lines from the first text file
    with open('C:/tmp/tmp1.txt', 'r') as f: #Open the first textfile
        line2 = f.readlines()   #Read these lines for later input
        for line2[count] in f:  #For each line from chosen starting line until last line from first text file,...
            with open('C:/tmp/tmp2.txt', 'a') as g: #...with the second textfile open for appending strings,...
                g.write("hello\n")  #...write 'hello\n' each time while "count" < "num_lines"
    count = count + 1   #Increment the "count"
```

I think everything works up until: "for line2[count] in f:"

The real code I'm working on is somewhat more complicated, and the application I'm using isn't exactly for sharing, so I have simplified the code to give silly outputs instead just to fix the problem.

I'm not looking for alternative code, I'm just looking for a reason why the loop isn't working so I can try to fix it myself.

All answers will be appreciated, and thanking everyone in advance!

Cormac

Comment: are you allowed to use `for line[count] in f:`?  Have you tried `for line in f:`?

Comment: Huh. Your problem is that `f` doesn't have any more lines to read after you do the `readlines()` call, so it puts a `None` in `line2[count]` (over what was there before).

Comment: It probably has to do with using `line2[count] in f`. If you create line2, you should use `for line in line2:`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could use the `for <variable> in <iterable>:` syntax like that. Though it seems like it could be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments:

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line1 in open('C:/tmp/tmp1.txt'))
```

Why? What's wrong with `len(open(filename, 'rb').readlines())`?

```
while (count < num_lines):
    ...
    count = count + 1
```

This is bad style, you could use:

```
for i in range(num_lines):
    ...
```

Note that I named your index `i`, which is universally recognized, and that I used `range` and a `for` loop.

Now, your problem, like I said in the comment, is that `f` is a file (that is, a stream of bytes with a location pointer) and you've read all the lines from it. So when you do `for line2[count] in f:`, it will try reading a line into `line2[count]` (this is a bit weird, actually, you almost never use a `for` loop with a list member as an index but apparently you can do that), see that there's no line to read, and never executes what's inside the loop.

Anyway, you want to read a file, line by line, starting from a given line number? Here's a better way to do that:

```
from itertools import islice

start_line = 0 # change this
filename = "foobar" # also this

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    for line in islice(f, start_line, None):
        print(line)
```

I realize you don't want alternative code, but your code really is needlessly complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason why I asked for no alternative code is because I like to learn things the hard way. That way I know I'll understand it better when I figure something out by myself, and I'll probably remember how to do it again forever. But I like that you've offered me "small" alternatives rather than one big alternative. That way I can take my time and investigate further. Thanks!

Comment: Is 'rb' reading a file in binary? Does this make more efficient code?

Comment: @FCormacB: The `b` is indeed short for binary, but in the sense of the FTP `BINARY` and `ASCII` commands. Without it, Python on Windows would convert between `\r\n` and `\n` when reading and writing files. I usually don't like my files being modified implicitly, so I use `b` when opening files. Short version -- it does nothing for efficiency, but for binary files (JPEG, MP3, ...) it's important for correctness.

Comment: @FCormacB: Reference: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @FCormacB: By the way, if you're going over the code, I should explain the rationale behind my usage of `islice` from `itertools` over regular `slice` or the `lines[start_line:]` syntax. The other options return a `list` object, which means they actually contain all the lines. This would mean you'd need to hold the entire file in memory, which would be problematic if the file is very big. `islice` returns an iterator which handles one line at a time, so it won't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the lines in the file f, I suggest replacing your "for" line with

```
for line in line2:
    # do something with "line"...
```

You put the lines in an array called line2, so use that array!  Using line2[count] as a loop variable doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I just changed the code above and I think it now works the way its meant to. Now I have to see if I can fix the real code. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to get it wrong how the 'for line in f' loop works. It iterates over a file and calls readline, until there are no lines to read. But at the moment you start the loop all the lines are already read(via f.readlines()) and file's current position is at end. You can achieve what you want by calling f.seek(0), but that doesn't seem to be a good decision anyway, since you're going to read file again and that's slow IO.
Instead you want to do smth like:

```
for line in line2[count:]: # iterate over lines read, starting with `count` line
    do_smth_with(line)
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll meddle around with that I think.